# ShareStatusTask immediately shuts down after opening in Windows Phone XNA

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, windows-phone

My game has highscores and I want my users to share them via social media (Twitter, Facebook).
I used ShareStatusTask before to let my users share things via social media, but when I use this feature in my XNA game. It just closes immediately (crashes?) after opening.

Anyone knows a solution for this? Or an other way to share highscores via social media?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** Sorry, I am super stupid, tested this on the emulator. When I tested it on my phone it insta-worked. Forgot the emulator got not settings for the share functionality. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What happens when you attach a debugger? Is an exception thrown?

Comment: Nothing happens, I use the default GameStateManagement from the AppHub though.